# How to reset css before repeating sequence

Tags: jquery, css, reset

I am new to JS and JQuery - I used to program in basic in the 80's and although I have a sketchy understanding of variables and arrays, I admit I haven't got to grip with all the brackets in js.
I know CSS and HTML well.

Through googling I have almost got what I want, which is for a line of text to move from R to L, fade and a new line to do the same thing. Perhaps have 4 of these text lines doing this and repeating infinitely.

For the sake of faster testing I have shortened the delays.

The one thing I can't get to happen is for the CSS left:400px to be reset before the animation begins all over again.

I don't know what to put or where to put it, but I have tried all of these, in many places!!
I used hello World to show me where the code is activated, it didn't help.

```
//function reset(this){  $(this).removeAttr('style');}
//$(this).css('left', '500');
//$(elements).css('left', '500');
//removeAttr( 'style' );
//$("elements").removeAttr("style");
//$("#elements").removeAttr("style");
 //.text("Hello World");
//$("#Test1").text("Hello, world!");
```

I don't understand very much about JQuery yet, but I've seen most of the code I'm using on several question & answer websites including here and I copied some comments into the code to help me understand what's happening.
I made my first jsfiddle to show the code. It begins immediately

http://jsfiddle.net/Stingraynut/Bf49z/3/

I hope someone here can help me reset the CSS back to left:400px after the 4 animations. Currently the first set of 4 work then the words all appear stuck left of screen, they don't go back to left:400px

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of jQuery functions have a **[callback function](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/#callbacks-and-functions)**. The one that is particularly useful in this case is the callback of the `.fadeOut()` function. By changing the CSS in the callback function, you can move it back after the transition.

```
$self.fadeOut(200, function(){
     $(this).css("left", "400px");   
 });
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bf49z/4/)

Comment: I just reset all the divs to left 400px everytime the function is called. Not sure if that is the right way to do it. http://jsfiddle.net/Bf49z/5/

Comment: Okay, but it's not fading out anymore. Did you take a look at my fiddle? It does exactly what you asked it to do. The problem with what you are doing is that you are moving it *before* it fades out. You are moving all of the elements over every time the function is called. If you put the movement in the callback (like in my answer), it will **fade out first** and then move.

Comment: Thanks very much David, I have a lot to learn. Someone called noobcode also answered, and it looks like you thought he was me, which he wasn't !
When the text first appears, it hangs in the first position for a moment, I would prefer it to be moving as it fades in. 
Is that the 'easing' function? and how would I add it, or if not, how can I have the text moving as it fades in?
I have changed the js fiddle to make the times longer, so the effect is more obvious. Eventually I want it to stop on the left for 3 seconds before fading.    http://jsfiddle.net/Stingraynut/Bf49z/8/

Comment: David, YES!! That is exactly what I was aiming for, thank  you very much.The link to an explanation of Callback is a site I have read, but it makes more sense having made a mistake and seeing how to do it. 

I put my script and yours side by side, to see what you’ve done, because it’s mostly a complete rewrite.
Thanks for the comments beside each line, it really helps
I notice also that the CSS ‘display’ is now ‘inline-block’ and ‘opacity:0; ‘ is added.
No room for questions, so have started a new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291054/trying-to-understand-a-jquery-routine